# A good method for client-side iframe caching

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, iframe, client-side

I'm trying to cache some documents client-side in order to switch between them faster.

The documents have been loaded in an iframe, so it's a question on how to cache it locally within the browser.

My method was to have a variable, item, and then do

```
if (item.cache) {
    $('.holder', someElem).html(item.cache);
    return;
}

item.cache = $('<iframe....');
$('.holder', someElem).html(item.cache);
```

However, this method keeps reloading the iframe src, when injected on to the holder.

Any good methods for client-side iframe caching?

Comment: If you want the opposite- do not cache iframe- see [Refresh iFrame (Cache Issue)](//stackoverflow.com/q/2524502)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `iframe` doesn't actually trigger a page refresh until it has been added to the `dom`. I am guessing you keep an instance of the `iframe` but not add it to the dom until its time to see it. This method doesn't work well. I would suggest using css "display:none" to load it and hide and then show it when you need it.

Comment: The hide/show works. Thanks :) We aren't able to stay away from iframe in this case.

Comment: "Stay away from iFrames"

Why? Just as HTML Tables are great for tabular data, and not for layouts, iFrames are awesome for doing what they are meant to do: frame another page inside of your webpage.

A loaded ajax page does not run scripts, or include styles into the parent page. You'd have to loop through those elements and trigger them manually, and even then, you'll get possible conflicts between classes.

Use an iFrame if you need to embed an external page, and maybe even an internal page in some instances.

Comment: "Stay away from iFrame", this is such a poor thing to say without having any context of the problem. How do you load a complete website inside a div and prevent it from polluting the scope of the outside of that div? Just stay away from iFrame, because someone has said something bad about them,

Answer (score 3):

HTTP has caching built in.  Mark Nottingham has written [a decent overview](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).  Setting the `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers should be enough for what you describe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But wouldn't this require the browser to first ask the server if there is an updated version, and then load it from its local cache afterwards?

Comment: No, that's what the `Expires` header is for.